# Integrability of first return time of Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a Markov chain with a possibly infinite state space $S$. Assume that $E_i(\tau_i)$ is finite for some $i$ in $S$, where $\tau_i = \inf\{k \geq 1 \colon X_k = i\}$. 
Is it true that $E_i(\tau_i^2)$ is finite?

Comment: The result is wrong. For **finite** Markov chains though, it holds and one can even show there exists some positive $c$ such that $$E_i(e^{c\tau_i})$$ is finite for every $i$.

Comment: Or rather, since your question got an answer, leave it as it is and ask another one where you do not forget some crucial hypothesis. ("Only one communicating class" and "finite state space" are two properties that are simply not related.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is wrong but a construction showing that it is, might be worth remembering.

Consider a Markov chain on the nonnegative integers whose transitions are from $0$ to $1$ with probability $p_0$, from $0$ to $0$ with probability $1-p_0$, and, for every positive $n$, from $n$ to $n+1$ with probability $p_n$ and from $n$ to $0$ with probability $1-p_n$. Thus, the paths of the Markov chains are the concatenation of some excursions $0\to0$ or $0\to1\to0$ or $0\to1\to2\to0$ or $0\to1\to2\to3\to0$ or... $0\to1\to2\to\cdots\to n-1\to n\to0$ for some nonnegative $n$. We assume that every $p_n$ is in $(0,1)$, to avoid degenerate cases.

It happens that one can *tune* the family of parameters $(p_n)$ to adjust the integrability properties of the return times.

To wit, the Markov chain described above is recurrent if and only if $\tau_0$ is finite $P_0$-almost surely if and only if $q_n\to0$, where, for every $n$, $$q_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}p_k$$ Furthermore, for every $n$, $$P_0(\tau_0\geqslant n+1)=q_n$$ hence the chain is positive recurrent if and only if $E_0(\tau_0)$ is finite if and only if the series $$\sum_nq_n$$ converges. Likewise, for every $i$, $E_i(\tau_i^2)$ is finite if and only if $E_0(\tau_0^2)$ is finite if and only if the series $$\sum_nnq_n$$ converges. Thus, one obtains positive recurrent Markov chains such that $E_0(\tau_0^2)$ diverges if (every $p_n$ is in $(0,1)$ and), for example, $$p_n=1-\frac{c}n+o\left(\frac1n\right)$$ when $n\to\infty$, for some $c$ in $(1,2)$.